# best python library for finding sequential rules mining?

Tags: python, data-mining, sequential-pattern-mining

I want to do sequence learning for that I want to find frequent sequential rules ,this rule consider the order of occurrence

Comment: I don't understand why this question is downvoted.

Comment: a simple method would be just to count them. If that does not satisfy you, you can use hidden markov model, conditional random fields, or even lstms.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could try Conditional Random Fields (https://github.com/scrapinghub/python-crfsuite) or a Long Short term Memory RNN (Keras+Tensorflow backend)

Comment: Thanks for reply .does it has any sequence rule mining algorithm  implemented .if no can you help me  in understanding the library

Answer (score 1):

I know this is possible with the [SPMF Java library](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=algorithms.php).

I created a Python wrapper for this recently. Handling sequential rules mining might require some adaption in the wrapper, since I use it mainly for sequential patterns mining, but it's certainly possible.

[GitHub link](https://github.com/LoLei/spmf-py)